# C++ Parameters Structure supporting strings and integers?

Tags: c++, parameters, var

How can I do this way easier:

```
struct Parameters {
public:
    int Parameter1;
    std::string Parameter1;
    int Parameter2;
    std::string Parameter2;
}
```

Isn't there "var" in C++ like in .NET ? I need parameters to be able to be integers and strings.

Comment: C#'s `var` is like `auto`. It doesn't mean variant. Use `boost::variant`.

Comment: C++ as such does not support "this type can be multiple types". There are some template library supper, such as `boost::variant`.

Comment: probably whatever it is should be a template, e.g. a function template

Answer (score 0):

You have the key word 'auto' in C++ but it's on C++0x and C++1x, it's the compiler which will decide the type and it can't change after the compilation.

You're probably looking for something like boost::variant: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: it's working with object, it's very usefull for iterator: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1848529

Comment: That's completely irrelevant to the above comment.

Comment: But how is that helping in the case that the question describes? Or are you just writing random "useful" things in an answer, not really meaningful to solve the actual problem in the question?

Comment: BTW, C++0x is obsolete, we have c++11 (and even c++14)

Comment: @Jarod42: BTW, there are shops that are still working with versions of C++ prior to 2011.  Some compiler manufacturers haven't upgraded and some shops won't upgrade their tools due to the effort required to validate the upgrade.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I mean, until specified some restriction in compiler, it is better to propose `-std=c++11` than `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union), but you will still need to know at compile time what type you are assigning. You can sort of hide this by using templates with implicit typing to assign values, but you will still have to know the appropriate type when reading the value. Not sure how useful that would be though.

You could also use polymorphism and your own (template) wrapper class in place of the built in types.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you factor out the common code and set up to use a factory.

**Use of a Factory**
The problem is that you don't know the type of the parameter until you parse the string.  The best method is to keep everything as a string or create a Factory and use a base class.  For more research, see "c++ factory design pattern example".

```
struct Base_Parameter
{
  std::string& parameter_as_string;
  virtual void extract_parameter(const std::string& parameter_string) = 0;
};

struct Int_Parameter : public Base_Parameter
{
  int  parameter_value;
  void extract_parameter(const std::string& parameter_string)
  {
    std::istringstream  param_stream(parameter_string);
    param_stream >> parameter_value;
  }
}
```

Your parameter "list" would be either a container of pointers to the base class (if the types are unknown) or you could have a container of the descendent struct:

```
struct Parameter_Container
{
  std::vector<Int_Parameter>  parameters;
};
```

As for the factory, the factory would be an object that could create parameter objects based on some criteria.  It would return a pointer to the base class.

*Note:  Unless you are on a tightly constrained platform, such as an embedded system, don't worry about overlapping memory locations to save room.*